# How to pass arguments to anonymous function in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, parameter-passing

Basically I need to pass an argument to an anonymous function in coffeescript, and I've ran out of ideas.

This is my code:

```
audio = {
        sounds: {},
        sources: [{
            wind: 'sounds/wind.mp3'
        }],
        load: (callback) ->
            this.totalFiles = Object.size(this.sources[0])
            for key of this.sources[0]
                sound = new Howl({ src: [this.sources[0][key]] })
                self = this
                sound.once('load', (key) =>
                    (key) ->
                        self.sounds[key] = this
                        if Object.size(self.sounds) == self.totalFiles
                            if typeof callback == 'function' then callback()
                (key)) <- THIS ARGUMENT PASSING DOES NOT COMPILE CORRECTLY
        loop: (name) ->
            this.sounds[name].loop(true)
            console.log this.sounds
    }
```

The code with callback.call():

```
load: (callback) ->
    this.totalFiles = Object.size(this.sources[0])
    for key of this.sources[0]
        sound = new Howl({ src: [this.sources[0][key]] })
        self = this
        sound.once('load', (key) =>
            callback.call(() ->
                self.sounds[key] = this
                if Object.size(self.sounds) == self.totalFiles
                    if typeof callback == 'function' then callback()
            , key)
        )
```

With callback.call() or callback.apply() I get the same result, the same compiled javascript. I tried to add (key) where I needed it in already compiled javascript, and it worked as intended.

Object size:

```
Object.size = (obj) ->
        size = 0
        for key in obj then if obj.hasOwnProperty(key) then size++
        return size
```

A good helper function I found on stackoverflow.

Comment: WTH is `Object.size`?

Comment: Added Object.size in the post body. Basically it's a function that calculates the size of an object, I found it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick for me:

```
sound.once('load', ((key) =>
    () ->
        self.sounds[key] = this
            if Object.size(self.sounds) == self.totalFiles
                if typeof callback == 'function' then callback()
        )(key)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some issues that are likely *hiding* the real problem:

- Inconsistent indenting
- `self = this` the callback to `sound.once` is a fat arrow function, meaning that the line
  `self.sounds[key] = this` this and self are the same
- Inclusion of lots of unnecessary braces.
- Inconsistent use of commas in object property definitions.

AFAIK the actual problem is that you're trying to call an IIFE, and you need parens:

```
sound.once('load', ((key) =>
    (key) ->
         self.sounds[key] = this
         if Object.size(self.sounds) == self.totalFiles
            if typeof callback == 'function' then callback()
)(key))
```

Except that you've over-used the name `key`. You've got a function that you're partially applying with a parameter named key, and then the returned function *also* takes a parameter named key? Which is it?

Comment: I've tried your code, the previous exception disappeared, but the object it returns is null.

Comment: console.log this.sounds -> returns Object {undefined: o}

Comment: Thats because key is undefined, see my update I just made.

Comment: I did the changes by myself, then copied your code, the output in console is still the same.